# How to Extract Single RGB Channel from Multiple Images Python

Tags: python, csv, rgb, cross-validation, converters

I'm a newbie in Python. 
I want to extract RGB values from multiple images. I want to use RGB values of every images as an input of K-Fold Cross Validation.

I can only get the RGB values of one image only. So I tried to get from multiple images with the following code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from PIL import Image
import glob

#Path to file 
for img in glob.glob({Path}+"*.jpg"):
    im = Image.open(img) 

#Load the pixel info
pix = im.load()

#Get a tuple of the x and y dimensions of the image
width, height = im.size

#Open a file to write the pixel data
with open('output_file.csv', 'w+') as f:
  f.write('R,G,B\n')

  #Read the details of each pixel and write them to the file
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      r = pix[x,y][0]
      g = pix[x,x][1]
      b = pix[x,x][2]
      f.write('{0},{1},{2}\n'.format(r,g,b))
```

I expect to get input like this in CSV file:

```
img_name,R,G,B
1.jpg,50,50,50
2.jpg,60,60,70
```

But the actual output is the CSV file contain 40000+ rows.

Is it possible to automate RGB value from multiple images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is currently writing the value of each pixel as a separate row in your CSV file, so you are likely to have a huge number of rows.

To work on multiple files, you need to rearrange your code a bit and indent the file writing inside your loop. It might also be a good idea to make use of Python's CSV library to write the CSV file just in case any of your filenames contain commas. If this happened, it would correctly wrap the field in quotes.

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os
import csv

#Open a file to write the pixel data
with open('output_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["img_name", "R", "G", "B"])

    #Path to file 
    for filename in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        im = Image.open(filename) 
        img_name = os.path.basename(filename)

        #Load the pixel info
        pix = im.load()

        #Get a tuple of the x and y dimensions of the image
        width, height = im.size

        print(f'{filename}, Width {width}, Height {height}') # show progress

        #Read the details of each pixel and write them to the file
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                r = pix[x,y][0]
                g = pix[x,y][1]
                b = pix[x,y][2]
                csv_output.writerow([img_name, r, g, b])
```

Note: There was also a problem with getting your `r` `g` `b` values, you had `[x,x]` in two cases.

---

As noted by @GiacomoCatenazzi, your loops could also be removed:

```
from itertools import product
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os
import csv

#Open a file to write the pixel data
with open('output_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["img_name", "R", "G", "B"])

    #Path to file 
    for filename in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        im = Image.open(filename) 
        img_name = os.path.basename(filename)

        #Load the pixel info
        pix = im.load()

        #Get a tuple of the x and y dimensions of the image
        width, height = im.size

        print(f'{filename}, Width {width}, Height {height}') # show 

        #Read the details of each pixel and write them to the file
        csv_output.writerows([img_name, *pix[x,y]] for x, y in product(range(width), range(height)))
```

Comment: `*pix[x,y]` instead of `r,g,b`, so you can remove 3 more lines, and you can see you can possible use an iteractor (and `writerows` and removing also the loops.

Comment: I already tried that code, but the csv output only contain the first row which is img_name, R, G, B. When the iteration #Path to file running, the csv file's status is closed. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Have you tried with different source images?  I have tested this on about 5 JPG files and it produces a huge number of rows.

Comment: Try adding `print(height, width)`

Comment: But the csv files is closed, that's why the iteration isn't working.

Comment: If there is a problem with your JPG image, `width` and `height` will probably be `0`. This would mean the loop would do nothing, and you would just get the header.

Comment: You should also see the filename being printed. If not, check the path is correct.